# Key input on html5 canvas not always responding

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to implement key input in a simple bouncing ball example, but some of the features doesn't respond properly. For example, if I try to stop the whole movement it works but the keyboard accuracy is not always the same. I guess this could be due to the loop, I mean, because I'm asking for the input in a loop, the computer answer is not the same depending on the moment I press the key. Also I'm trying to pause the loop setting up a condition to recall the loop inside itself, and while this is working when I use the mouse, it doesn't when I use the keyboard.

You can see the code here, keys involved are 'D' to start the movement and stop it, 's' and 'a' to speed down and speed up, arrows to move around and space to pause. Pause is not working at all. It pauses the animation but doesn't reload it.

[link to pen](http://codepen.io/pboest/pen/qChba)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick play with your codepen and got it working by removing the logicLoop completely and putting a check on the d key in the animationFrame loop:

```
function graphicLoop(){
    context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);      // Clean the canvas
    draw();
    requestAnimationFrame(graphicLoop);

    if(keys[68]){ 
        update();
    }
}
graphicLoop();
```

Comment: But this does something different. I don't want the balls moving just while I'm pressing the key, but to stop them or put them into movement pressing once, as my code did (with troubles recognizing the input). The other problem was related with space bar, because it freeze but doesn't unfreeze.

Comment: I see. At any rate I would recommend using one central loop that uses requestAnimationFrame and calling the logicLoop function from there. Also try handling single presses in a keypressed function that fires onkeydown instead of checking if the key is down in the loop.